# Compile structs in c separate files

Tags: c, gcc, struct, compilation

I want to compile two C separate files, one which will contain a struct type like

```
typedef struct {  
  int renglones;  
  int columnas;  
} Matriz
```

And in another file make the call to that struct and use it, but when I try to compile but files, mark error, I want to know if there's a way to do this, or can't be done.

Comment: Declare your struct in a header file and include that header from both source files.

Comment: You can declare an object of a `struct` type and perform various operations on it, but you can't "call" it; only functions can be called.

Comment: How to use [C -Header Files](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_header_files.htm)

Comment: If you intend to make `Matriz` opaque to the other C file, then you also need to define a public interface to manipulate `Matriz`.

Comment: Oks, I'm gonna for the header file option, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't fully understood what you are trying to do. However, the definition of structure should be within and header file, for example a Matriz.h. 
Once you have define this file you can use the new structure by including Matriz.h via the include keyword in both files. This is the correct way to define a structure which is used by multiple files.

For example :

**Matriz.h**

```
#ifndef MATRIZ_H
#define MATRIZ_H

typedef struct {  
    int renglones;  
    int columnas;  
} Matriz;


#endif /* end of include guard: MATRIZ_H */
```

Then in your c file , you can just use

```
#include "Matriz.h"
```

You get a error because the compile does not know the size of the Matriz object when it is  compiling the file where the structure is not defined.

Let me know if you need more info.